# snap svg high cpu usage with animate

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I'm using snapsvg.js to animate some svg objects of a SVG i made with Inkscape.
I would like theses svg objects to loop indefinitely (infinite looping animation)

The following code is working (the loop animation works) but the CPU usage is very very high (80%) (tested in latest Chrome, Chrome 43)

Even if i remove the recalling of a1() in the animation end callback, the CPU remmains very high.

Why snap svg is consuming so much CPU just for a little animation (i just translate 3 little SVG objects) ???

Thanks a lot for your help !

Eviral

```
function potionize()
{
    var s = Snap("#potionsvg");
    Snap.load("assets/img/potion.svg", function (f)
    {
        var g = f.select("g");
        g.click(click);
        s.append(g);

        var b1 = Snap.select('#b1');
        var b2 = Snap.select('#b2');
        var b3 = Snap.select('#b3');

        var a1 = function()
        { 
            b1.attr({transform: "t0 0"});
            b2.attr({transform: "t0 0"});
            b3.attr({transform: "t0 0"});
            b1.animate({'transform' : 't0 -110'}, 1100, mina.linear);
            b2.animate({'transform' : 't0 -150'}, 1500, mina.linear);
            b3.animate({'transform' : 't0 -200'}, 2100, mina.linear, a1);
        }

        a1();
    })
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to put it on a jsfiddle with the potion.svg bit all working ?